# Permanently permit (single) Unsigned Driver on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers

I am a field technician and work with some older software/equipment. The equipment is still being manufactured, but the software stack is older and there are no signed drivers available for a software modem required to communicate with the equipment via LCT.

I require to permanently install a unsigned driver into Windows 10 for use with certain equipment. The complication comes with each insert of the USB modem having a different ID and therefore a different driver is required to be installed as the computer sees it as a new device.

Although the driver is available via "Find driver on my PC", once I have re-enabled Driver Signing Enforcement in Windows 10 the "new" modem is installed but is not functioning due to the driver signing issue.

Is there a way to add a permanent exemption for a specific driver to be installed multiple times? Currently I am having to reboot into Advanced Recovery mode to disable driver signing enforcement and reinstall driver each time. This in turn means I cannot properly enable Secure Boot, etc., etc.

Comment: See this page....https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-unsigned-drivers-windows10/

Comment: It is not possible to only allow a single unsigned driver and have driver signature enforcement enabled.  It is impossible to install and use an unsigned driver and enable Secure Boot